# bootstrap combobox and onchange selection value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap combobox plugin and now I'm having problem with changing selection and sending that data from the view to the controller

```
$('#MyCombo').on('change', function () {
    var data = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
     $.ajax({
      ...
      data: { comboId: comboId},
      ...
     });
});
```

code works without boostrap combobox plugin, but with plugin I'm getting null selected value on combo change.

How to fix this?

update: https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox

Comment: can you post the link to your plugin?

Comment: change: {comboId: comboId} to:  {comboId: data}

Comment: @MarcusH that obviously is not the problem :)

Comment: ok, Just brought it up as you havn't declared comboId in your example. I suggest you to try and use $().change() instead of $().on(). And you can just use $(this).val() to get the selected value of the combobox.

Comment: @user1765862 can you provide any other link reference for more demos of this plugin?? I might know what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

> code works without boostrap combobox plugin, but with plugin I'm
>   getting null selected value on combo change.

The problem here is that after you apply the plugin, your select element is no more available. Its replaced with `input`, `div`, `ul` and `li's`. This is how the plugin gets that UI look. So your change event on the select tag will not trigger because you are not even playing with it anymore, Its not on the UI anymore. `With plugins like this there are events which are supported by the plugin, like say on change, on select, on deselect etc`. I had a look into your plugin documentation and **Unfortunately this plugin does not support on change event on it.**  So with this plugin I dont think you can trigger the change event.